# Ubuntu Remix on Acer Aspire One Netbook keeps freezing

Tags: ubuntu, acer-aspire

It came with a Windows XP installation and I just couldn't deal with the screen constantly blacking out. Later on I found out they designed a specific key on this netbook for it. Anyways I installed Ubuntu Remix and it fixed it. However a lot of bad things are happening now.

1) If I want a long video or lots of music it will lockup after an hour.

2) Plugging it to an external monitor for more then 1 hour will black out.

3) Constantly running fsck after a lockup and then I lose nodes / fragments and what not :(

I am really not sure what to do, both blacking out and lockups really mess my hard drive up. I have to manually run fsck every time it happens. My gf has the same kind of netboot w/ Remix (not the same model number) and it runs perfectly fine on hers. Except for skype eating up all her CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been running unr for a while on an aspire one and haven't had these kind of problems.  It's probably worth checking it's not going into power save since there are known issues with this.  Also it might be worth getting hold of a copy of acerfand and tweaking it's settings to see if you can force the pc to run a little cooler.

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it sounds, there are reports of hard drive corruption when the speakers on an Aspire One are turned up. I'm not sure if that was the culprit, but I has similar problems on my first Aspire. Never got to the bottom of it though, as it was stolen before I had time to figure it out.

I believe the speaker issue has been fixed in newer models (my second Aspire seems to have an even lower 'max' volume then my first).

Here's a link to the story: http://www.engadget.com/2009/03/26/8-9-inch-acer-aspire-one-said-to-have-hard-drive-flaw-distaste/